# Mediawiki link within the page to a specific place, rather than a section

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

**1. Question**

If I code like the following, then I have a link within the page to a specific "section"

```
[[#SectionTitle|displayed text]]
```

But what if I want to have a link within the page to a place, I mean any place?

Sometimes I might want to directly refer to a part of the page that isn't at the start of a section.

**2. What I tried**

I tried something like this

```
[[#Foo|displayed text]]
{{anchor|Foo}}
```

This seemed to ask me to make a page Template:Anchor

So I copied the Template:Anchor page of wikipedia.

But Template:Anchor again seemed to ask to make some new page, because Template:Anchor only says

```
{{#invoke:anchor|main}}
```

So my attempt didn't work.

Comment: link to official mediawiki help on anchors for section headers: ["Section headings and the top of the page are automatically anchored"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following to create the anchor:

```
<div id="NameOfAnchorHere">optional text</div>
```

which can be referenced as:

```
[[#NameOfAnchorHere| test]]
```

More information about linking in MediaWiki can be found [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links#Internal_links)

Comment: By the way, putting <div id="anchor1"></div> seems to cause line break. But I don't want to break line there. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try `<div id="anchor1" style="display:inline;"></div>`

Answer (score 2):

And just to explain what's going on with `{{#invoke:anchor|main}}`: that's using [Lua code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Anchor) in the `Module` namespace to generate the anchor.

Note that it eventually uses

```html
<span id="NameOfAnchorHere">optional text</span>
```

which, I think, is nearly equivalent of `<div style="display:inline;">`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Put the closing tag at the end of the paragraph, not right after the anchor. That will then not cause a line break. Or use the span tag which can be immediately after the anchor.

Comment: Could you please write some example code? I'm also unsure why you're mentioning line breaks, because the original question asker didn't mention that. Does this answer the question?